# Compiling C++ file with Header on Atom

Tags: c++, header, atom-editor

So I am using Atom for a while but using it for the time for C++.
I am getting a compilation error when I run the

> Object Oriented Coding.cpp file

cpp file if I include my own header file for some reason.
The cpp code is:

```
/* Object Oriented Coding.cpp file */
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h" // Our madeup header file
using namespace std;

int main(){

  speak();
  return 0;
}
```

The header file is:

```
/* Cat.h file with my prototypes */
#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

void speak();

#endif
```

The function file is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void speak(){
 cout << "Meow Meow ..." << endl;
}
```

I am using the gcc-make-run package to compile my c++ code. Also all of the above files are in the same folder

The compilation error is:

> C:\Users\JAPNIT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIb2JOh.o:Object Oriented Coding.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `speak()'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgiHY.png)

Comment: I have added the error image link

Comment: Your code compiles successfully. You're issue is that the _linker_ is unable to produce an executable since it can't find the definition for `speak`. Try passing **both** the file with your `main` function and the file that defines `speak` to `g++`.

Comment: The errors need to be included _as text_, not images.  See [ask].

Comment: @Brian Is there no way I can write functions in a separate cpp file and link it to main in atom ?

Comment: @JapnitSethi You most certainly can, just not with the `g++` command your are currently using. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532400/linking-files-in-g)